# Scroll only one div's content with main scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying but I'm not coming up with a solution to this fairly simple problem.

Basically what I want is to have a fixed body with a vertically and horizontally centered rectangular div hosting my content. The body won't scroll, but the div's content should.

In other words, what I'm going for is basically having a full page, whole background on the lower layer (say, a full width image) and a div hosting my content on top of this background layer, scrolling independently.

What I have in my code are basically three nested layers:

1) the body (overflow:hidden), 2) a full width transparent container (overflow-y: scroll) and 3) the centered div that is supposed to host all my content (position: absolute).

Problem is, **nothing is scrolling**. If I try to add overflow-y: scroll or auto to the centered div, an ugly scrollbar appears right on it and that's not what I want - I want to use the "main" body scrollbar for scrolling.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: red;
} 

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 60px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsum </h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vulputate 
    arcu sit amet quam malesuada, maximus ornare quam facilisis. Fusce eu lectus 
    sapien. Nunc condimentum, neque ut porta tincidunt, sem mi hendrerit nisi, 
    eget blandit elit diam nec
      enim. Vivamus imperdiet nisi auctor nisl auctor, at aliquam lectus luctus. 
    Mauris non sem tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis pharetra commodo tempor. Fusce 
    luctus posuere fringilla. Morbi molestie tortor quis lectus sodales 
    vulputate. Aenean pharetra interdum tellus, nec congue nisi venenatis eu. 
    Cras eget metus et sapien aliquam dictum eget eu massa.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vulputate 
    arcu sit amet quam malesuada, maximus ornare quam facilisis. Fusce eu lectus 
    sapien. Nunc condimentum, neque ut porta tincidunt, sem mi hendrerit nisi, 
    eget blandit elit diam nec
      enim. Vivamus imperdiet nisi auctor nisl auctor, at aliquam lectus luctus. 
    Mauris non sem tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis pharetra commodo tempor. Fusce 
    luctus posuere fringilla. Morbi molestie tortor quis lectus sodales 
    vulputate. Aenean pharetra interdum tellus, nec congue nisi venenatis eu. 
    Cras eget metus et sapien aliquam dictum eget eu massa.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vulputate 
    arcu sit amet quam malesuada, maximus ornare quam facilisis. Fusce eu lectus 
    sapien. Nunc condimentum, neque ut porta tincidunt, sem mi hendrerit nisi, 
    eget blandit elit diam nec
      enim. Vivamus imperdiet nisi auctor nisl auctor, at aliquam lectus luctus. 
    Mauris non sem tortor. Nulla facilisi. Duis pharetra commodo tempor. Fusce 
    luctus posuere fringilla. Morbi molestie tortor quis lectus sodales 
    vulputate. Aenean pharetra interdum tellus, nec congue nisi venenatis eu. 
    Cras eget metus et sapien aliquam dictum eget eu massa.</p>
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here's a fiddle where you can see what I'm going for:

https://jsfiddle.net/ohmlg/29mL6tnv/

What I want:

1) have the div's contents stay inside the div as I scroll (right now, the overflow: hidden property on the body is cutting off part of the content)
2) use the main scrollbar for scrolling the contents inside the div

I can't implement a workaround like having four thick divs top right bottom and left (basically leaving a rectangular "window" in the middle), because I want to have two backgrounds: one on the bottom layer (body or .container) and one on the "content div".

Comment: _“I want to use the "main" body scrollbar for scrolling”_ – then you should realize that setting overflow:hidden for body is counter-productive in that regard ...

Comment: I don't believe this will be achievable. It's either the content breaks out of the `overlay` div and you have the scrollbar on the page, or you need to have a scrollbar on the right-hand side of the `overlay` div.

Comment: @CBroe, that doesn't solve my problem unfortunately.

Comment: will this be a full page structure?

Comment: @JoshuaM, that's what it looks like right now. Maybe somebody knows some workaround.

Comment: @SahilDhir I'm not sure if I understand your question, but yes, the .container layer is supposed to be full page, while the .overlay div is only a portion of it.

Comment: @m3b93 there is a turnaround.. check this example http://jsfiddle.net/7Ujj6/2/

Comment: @SahilDhir, oh I saw that fiddle! :) Unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for (maybe it is actually unachievable?). What I'm going for is basically having a full page, *whole* background on the lower layer (say, a full width image) and a div hosting my content on top of this background layer, scrolling independently.

Comment: maybe jquery can help here..

Comment: you want something like https://jsfiddle.net/29mL6tnv/1/?

Comment: It's fairly easy to have the scrollbar be on the right window edge like you want, but with the top and bottom lining up with the content area (not full height). Would that be sufficient for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not directly possible, but it is possible to make it *seem* so by covering up certain parts...

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10vh 10vw;
}

body, .bg {
  background-color: #ddd;
  background-image: url('https://lorempixel.com/638/220/abstract/');
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

p {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#padding-top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

#padding-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
}

#content-outline {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  right: 10vw;
  bottom: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

#content {
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc sodales nunc eu est semper eleifend. Sed vulputate nulla sit amet hendrerit finibus. Donec dapibus turpis eget mauris ultricies lobortis. Curabitur in est a felis lacinia facilisis eu quis tortor. Quisque eget augue luctus, tristique ligula fermentum, efficitur sapien. Aenean ut nisi risus. Sed libero ligula, venenatis vel dictum nec, suscipit a nisl. Maecenas a lacus et urna commodo aliquam. Quisque gravida maximus ipsum nec interdum. Donec nec aliquet mauris. Phasellus laoreet sit amet erat at ornare. Donec rutrum nulla libero, eget sollicitudin ligula convallis dapibus. Donec sodales, lorem lacinia rutrum tempus, mi nunc ultricies justo, non dignissim turpis diam id urna. In suscipit gravida elit quis tristique. Vivamus quis sapien vestibulum, elementum mi in, sodales quam. Donec enim elit, lacinia vitae urna a, tincidunt sagittis nunc.</p>
  <p>Nullam pretium, libero non viverra suscipit, mauris elit egestas odio, eget commodo purus ipsum vel purus. Morbi eleifend libero mauris, feugiat bibendum ante pretium id. Morbi fringilla fringilla convallis. Nulla ullamcorper dui et quam pellentesque, ut finibus dolor sodales. Donec laoreet, augue ac ornare pretium, nulla est imperdiet elit, non euismod urna mi a risus. Proin id commodo neque. Aliquam scelerisque imperdiet elementum. Phasellus dignissim rhoncus nibh, sed efficitur massa aliquam id. Curabitur sit amet turpis dictum, pellentesque leo sed, congue urna. Morbi maximus volutpat neque, vitae molestie urna ornare a. Suspendisse ut tincidunt urna.</p>
  <p>Proin eget nisl at lacus placerat aliquam. Curabitur tempus consectetur nulla eu malesuada. Nulla at tortor quis erat ornare ultricies. Aenean dolor erat, tempor in risus vel, fringilla sollicitudin risus. Quisque porttitor metus eget ante ullamcorper faucibus. Curabitur placerat turpis ac aliquet rhoncus. Aenean fringilla fringilla urna, a consectetur tellus aliquet non. Sed dapibus, ex vitae lacinia sodales, ex nisl pulvinar nulla, et tempus nulla tortor at tellus. Vivamus ac consequat eros. Fusce ullamcorper leo sed malesuada tincidunt. Integer ullamcorper blandit eros in scelerisque.</p>
  <p>Nunc fermentum sapien orci, id feugiat lectus aliquet gravida. Sed imperdiet posuere nulla, sed aliquam est mollis at. Donec faucibus justo at velit tincidunt elementum. Quisque eget maximus nunc, eget pulvinar mi. Donec venenatis diam erat, non porttitor sem tempus ut. Donec dictum odio sed ornare pulvinar. Aliquam ac nulla velit. Ut nec magna ut nulla ornare imperdiet id ut ante. Aliquam placerat laoreet pharetra. Donec ante purus, maximus ac nisi ullamcorper, egestas vestibulum diam. In ultricies ante a nibh vestibulum, ut gravida nulla pulvinar.</p>
  <p>Suspendisse purus ex, tempus a accumsan ac, gravida eu quam. Proin venenatis est quis laoreet congue. Fusce nec efficitur dolor. Vestibulum eleifend felis non ultrices pretium. Mauris auctor eget risus non luctus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Fusce varius non lacus non porttitor. Integer a turpis at lacus consequat sollicitudin. Vestibulum eget mi at enim imperdiet hendrerit ut ut nibh. Aliquam placerat sodales finibus. Nulla porttitor dolor sed nisi tincidunt vehicula a sit amet ligula. Aenean turpis ex, tempor sed urna et, tristique pretium velit. Mauris est risus, porta id dui a, tristique hendrerit odio. Sed ultricies consectetur gravida. Aenean vestibulum elit venenatis, condimentum sapien at, consectetur augue.</p>
</div>
<div id="padding-top" class="bg"></div>
<div id="padding-bottom" class="bg"></div>
<div id="content-outline"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is good advice; unfortunately, it's not what I'm looking for.  What I'm going for is basically having a full page, fixed, whole background on the lower layer (say, a full width image) and a div hosting my content on top of this background layer, capable of scrolling through the browser's default scrollbar. However, it looks like it's unachievable, although I could swear I've seen this effect on a couple of websites.

Comment: @mrb93 I have updated my answer to include a background image. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: my man! This is hacky in the best way possible. It works just like I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the same overflow attribute to the overlay element

```
.overlay {
      overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Depending on what you want, you don't really need the overflow on the container, you only need it on the parent of the element that will be overflowing in this case the p

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that puts a scrollbar on the right of my .overlay div, which I'm trying to avoid. I'd like to use the browser's default scrollbar for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try achieve something similar you could do it with fixed headers and footers.

```
#header {
    background-color:red;
    width:100vw;
    height:20px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}

#footer {
    background-color:red;
    width:100vw;
    height:20px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Here is an example
https://jsfiddle.net/10mh3tue/